# How to determine client pc date format

Tags: php, date, client

Is there any way by which we can find Date Format as set in the computer where web pages are loading?

I want to show date in my web pages according to what is set in client machine system.

I have seem an ASP based web page which lists all the system setting of a clients system including information of drivers installed!

So if it is possible in ASP then I think this should be possible in PHP also!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such information available to server PHP script. You can examine HTTP headers. There are often headers

```
Accept-Language
Accept-Charset
```

Those can be use to identify user language and guess his preferences (guess not retrieve his real preferences).

More complicated approach is to use Javascript function `dateObject.toLocaleDateString()` and try to parse that and identify user preferences in the browser and send that information to the server. I don't know of any library that can do that, but you may try to find that.

Comment: Just for the record, if everything else fails, you could also try to guess the locale of the computer based on the geographic location of the IP.

Answer (score 0):

In a web page running on a client's machine, you can access what is provided by the browser - nothing else (by design, for security reasons). You cannot, for example read or write a file.

If you are talking about linguistic and cultural aspects of displaying a date, then you need to look at the Locale: Javascript for example has a method Date.toLocaleDateString().

If you are talking about something else (eg the particular textual layout adopted by the operating system), no you cannot find out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a module in Apache that calls geoip so that you can recognize the country of the user. Then you can set the time zone to show it to the user in his time zone.

Example:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

if (date_default_timezone_get()) {
    echo 'date_default_timezone_set: ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '<br />';
}

if (ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    echo 'date.timezone: ' . ini_get('date.timezone');
}

?>
```

You can read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php).

Comment: I think this will do the trick. I will try this out as a work around.